# How to uninstall installed plugin in created RCP project?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, p2

I have created **RCP Project** which have only Install New Software functionality, i installed a plugin through **Install New Software** and i want to uninstall that plugin, Is there any way to uninstall the plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse use Help -> About eclipse IDE ->Installation details

This will show all installed plugins in eclipse. You can select one and uninstall that.